# Making quicktabs module responsive

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, responsive-design

I am using the premium responsive theme for drupal 7, and added the quick-tabs module to the front-page. Currently the body of the quicktab module is resizing with the screen, but the tabs are stacking on top of each other. Is it possible to make the tabs (along with the font) adjust so they remain side-by-side?

Comment: Without seeing your CSS its hard to give a clear cut answer.  If the tabs are in LIs then you can simply make them inline or inline-block.  Try and post some CSS if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem with this. Look at the layout.css folder that the theme gives you and model it for the quicktabs. You want to give the quicktabs a specific 'threshold' that will adjust the width when a certain screen size is hit. I then put a small snippet of php in that took the tabs and changed them from tabs to a clickable drop-down. I won't give you the code as it's in your best interest to learn it yourself. Goodluck and I hope this sent you in the right direction!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your small snippet of PHP work? How does PHP detect when the screen size is smaller than the threshold?

Answer (score 1):

The Quick Tabs module does not automatically output width's or heights, so you can just use responsive CSS techniques to achieve this.  http://drupal.org/node/1377736